# C: Double is returning different results

Tags: c

This code works up until to the end of the Visible Spectrum, but when you type Decimal points it show wrong results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SENTINEL 0
int main ()
{
    int  wavelength=0, power=0;
    printf("Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");
    scanf("%dE %d", &wavelength, &power);
    while (wavelength!=SENTINEL)
    {printf("\nYou inputted : %dE%d which is %d x 10^%d and belong to the region of ", wavelength, power, wavelength, power);
    if(wavelength==3 && power>=-11 && power<-9)printf("Gamma Ray.");
    else if(wavelength==3&&power==-9){printf("X-ray.");}
    else if(wavelength==4&&power==-7){printf("Ultraviolet.");}
    else if(wavelength==7&&power==-7){printf("Visible Spectrum.");}
    else if(wavelength=1.4&&power==-5){printf("Infrared.");}
    else if(wavelength==.1&&power==-1){printf("Microwaves.");}
    else printf("Radiowaves");
    printf("\n\nEnter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");
    scanf("%dE %d", &wavelength, &power);}
}
```

Output:

```
You inputted : 1E0 which is 1 x 10^0 and belong to the region of Radiowaves

Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:
```

I knew that it should be double so it can store decimal values, but when I try it, it is showing more wrong results: Can somebody help me?

```
#define SENTINEL 0
int main ()
{
    double wavelength=0, power=0;
    printf("Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");
    scanf("%lfE %lf", &wavelength, &power);
    while (wavelength!=SENTINEL)
    {printf("\nYou inputted : %.2lfE%.2lf which is %.2lf x 10^%.2lf and belong to the region of ", wavelength, power, wavelength, power);
    if(wavelength==3 && power>=-11 && power<-9)printf("Gamma Ray.");
    else if(wavelength==3&&power==-9){printf("X-ray.");}
    else if(wavelength==4&&power==-7){printf("Ultraviolet.");}
    else if(wavelength==7&&power==-7){printf("Visible Spectrum.");}
    else if(wavelength=1.4&&power==-5){printf("Infrared.");}
    else if(wavelength==.1&&power==-1){printf("Microwaves.");}
    else printf("Radiowaves");
    printf("\n\nEnter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");
    scanf("%lfE %lf", &wavelength, &power);}
}
```

Output:

```
Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  1.4E-5

You inputted : 0.00E0.00 which is 0.00 x 10^0.00 and belong to the region of Radiowaves

Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:
```

The output should be Infrared. How you guys help :)

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "until to the end of the Visible Spectrum". We are programmers but not necessarily experts in whatever your domain is. You need to explain the problem to us in programming terms. That is, what is the the program supposed to do and what is the input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Consider it a x. It is not important btw. i just want to know how to store a value to double, yet it gives me wrong results. :)

Comment: Yeah but what does "wrong result" mean? We can't help you if we don't understand what the problem is. To store a double you do `double my_double = value;`. But obviously that's not what you are asking. But it's not clear what you *are* asking.

Comment: You are making it much harder than it needs to be to read the wavelength.  The `%f` field directive and those derived from it accept exponential notation, so you don't need to read and combine two separate fields.  That you *do* attempt to read and combine separate fields could be related to your mysterious wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty. You have to tweak it.

```
#define SENTINEL 0

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


double wavelength = 0, power = 0;
char line[20];

void read_base_exponent_double(char *line)
{
    char *ptr = line;
    size_t n;
    char base_buf[10];
    char power_buf[10];

    while (*ptr != 'E') ptr++;
    n = ptr - line;
    strncat(base_buf, line, n);
    wavelength = strtod(base_buf, NULL);
    ptr++;
    strcat(power_buf, ptr);
    power = strtod(power_buf, NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9"
           "// Enter 0 to quit:  ");

    fgets(line, 20, stdin);
    read_base_exponent_double(line);

    while (wavelength != SENTINEL) {
        printf("\nYou inputted : %.2lfE%.2lf which is %.2lf x 10^%.2lf "
               "and belong to the region of ",
               wavelength, power, wavelength, power);

        if (wavelength == 3 && power >= -11 && power < -9) {
            printf("Gamma Ray.");
        } else if (wavelength == 3 && power == -9) {
            printf("X-ray.");
        } else if (wavelength == 4 && power == -7) {
            printf("Ultraviolet.");
        } else if (wavelength == 7 && power == -7) {
            printf("Visible Spectrum.");
        } else if (wavelength = 1.4 && power == -5) {
            printf("Infrared.");
        } else if (wavelength == .1 && power == -1) {
            printf("Microwaves.");
        } else
            printf("Radiowaves");

        printf("\n\nEnter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x "
               "10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");
        fgets(line, 20, stdin);
        read_base_exponent_double(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried to enter 1.4E-5 : The Output is Radiowaves, it should be Infrared.

Comment: My output is Infrared here.

Comment: Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9// Enter 0 to quit:  1.4E-5

You inputted : 1.40E0.00 which is 1.40 x 10^0.00 and belong to the region of Radiowaves

Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:

Comment: OK. I compiled it with another compiler it doesn't work. I don't know now. I produced a bug somehow.

Comment: I also don't what causing the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
#define SENTINEL 0
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

double wavelength = 0.0, power = 0.0;
char line[20];

void read_base_exponent_double(char *line)
{
    const char delimeter[] = "Ee ";
    char *token = strtok(line, delimeter);
    int counter = 0;

    while (token != NULL) {
        if (isdigit(token[0]) && counter == 0) {
            counter++;
            wavelength = strtod(token, NULL);
        } else if ((isdigit(token[0]) || token[0] == '-') && counter == 1) {
            counter++;
            power = strtod(token, NULL);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delimeter);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x 10^-9"
           "// Enter 0 to quit:  ");

    fgets(line, 20, stdin);
    read_base_exponent_double(line);

    while (wavelength != SENTINEL) {
        printf("\nYou inputted : %.2lfE%.2lf which is %.2lf x 10^%.2lf "
               "and belong to the region of ",
               wavelength, power, wavelength, power);

        if (wavelength == 3 && power >= -11 && power < -9) {
            printf("Gamma Ray.");
        } else if (wavelength == 3 && power == -9) {
            printf("X-ray.");
        } else if (wavelength == 4 && power == -7) {
            printf("Ultraviolet.");
        } else if (wavelength == 7 && power == -7) {
            printf("Visible Spectrum.");
        } else if (wavelength == 1.4 && power == -5) {
            printf("Infrared.");
        } else if (wavelength == 0.1 && power == -1) {
            printf("Microwaves.");
        } else {
            printf("Radiowaves");
        }

        printf("\n\nEnter wavelength using scientific notation (e.g. 3E-9) >> 3 x "
               "10^-9 // Enter 0 to quit:  ");

        fgets(line, 20, stdin);
        read_base_exponent_double(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you got a result when you enter .1E-1 which os microwave?

Comment: and when I'm trying to enter ranges that are not on those condition, it gives me the same result.

Comment: Enter 0.1E-1. What ranges? It's your program logic. The function can't handle every possible string. It's relatively specific.

Comment: Yeah, have you tried entering .1E-1, that should fall for microwaves. but is showing different results

Comment: when I tried entering .1E-1 it doesn't give me a 'microwave' result

Comment: I see. Maybe some kind of double precision difficulties here. I can't figure it out now.

Comment: I can't understand your code, because I'm still learning to do C, hope you understand. :)

Comment: Thanks! I found a bug when I'm trying to enter .1E-1 it shows no results yet when I try to include 0 before the dot. 0.1E-1 it perfectly works fine now. Thanks rifkin for your expert answer. Greetings from the Philippines!

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf line is wrong. Maybe use fgets to read the line and than use atof to read the next double value.